# Заливка звезд рэйтинга в формате SVG при наведении

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, svg

Есть блок со звездами рейтинга. Код работает, звезды закрашиваются при наведении.
Сами звёзды реализованы через ограничение `viewBox`'а и смещения самой звезды. Т.е. одна звезда состоит из двух. Если обратить внимание, то первая половина каждой последующей звезды начинает закрашиваться когда курсор еще не покинул предыдущую. Возможна ли реализация данного примера так, чтобы звезды закрашивались только при наведении на них, но не раньше?

Код по [ссылке](https://codepen.io/andrewshevtsov/pen/OdWERQ) в демо.

Буду благодарен за Ваши идеи!

```js
$('.star.rating').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().attr('data-stars', $(this).data('rating'));
});
```

```css
.stars {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.star1 {
  margin: 0 0 0 -17px;
}

.star1-2 {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.star2 {
  margin: 0 0 0 -15px;
}

.star2-2 {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.star3 {
  margin: 0 0 0 -15px;
}

.star3-2 {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.star4 {
  margin: 0 0 0 -15px;
}

.star4-2 {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.star5 {
  margin: 0 0 0 -15px;
}

.star5-2 {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.stars:hover .star path {
  fill: #f1641d !important;
}

.stars .star {
  float: left;
}

.stars .star path {
  fill: #d8d8d8;
}

.stars .star:hover~.star path {
  fill: #d8d8d8 !important;
}

.stars[data-stars] .star path {
  fill: #f1641d;
}

.stars[data-stars="1"] .star:nth-child(1)~.star path {
  fill: #d8d8d8;
}

.stars[data-stars="1.5"] .star:nth-child(2)~.star path {
  fill: #d8d8d8;
}

.stars[data-stars="2"] .star:nth-child(3)~.star path {
  fill: #d8d8d8;
}

.stars[data-stars="2.5"] .star:nth-child(4)~.star path {
  fill: #d8d8d8;
}

.stars[data-stars="3"] .star:nth-child(5)~.star path {
  fill: #d8d8d8;
}

.stars[data-stars="3.5"] .star:nth-child(6)~.star path {
  fill: #d8d8d8;
}

.stars[data-stars="4"] .star:nth-child(7)~.star path {
  fill: #d8d8d8;
}

.stars[data-stars="4.5"] .star:nth-child(8)~.star path {
  fill: #d8d8d8;
}

.stars[data-stars="5"] .star:nth-child(9)~.star path {
  fill: #d8d8d8;
}

.stars[data-stars="5.5"] .star:nth-child(10)~.star path {
  fill: #d8d8d8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stars" data-stars="1">
  <svg class="star star1" width="22" height="22" viewBox="-9 0 20 20" data-rating="1">
              <path d="M10.53 16.081l6.5 3.926-1.72-7.4 5.74-4.98-7.56-.65-2.96-6.981-2.96 6.981-7.56.65 5.74 4.98-1.72 7.4z" style="fill-rule:nonzero;"></path>
            </svg>
  <svg class="star rating star1-2" width="22" height="22" viewBox="10 0 20 20" data-rating="1.5">
              <path d="M10.53 16.081l6.5 3.926-1.72-7.4 5.74-4.98-7.56-.65-2.96-6.981-2.96 6.981-7.56.65 5.74 4.98-1.72 7.4z" style="fill-rule:nonzero;"></path>
            </svg>
  <svg class="star rating star2" width="22" height="22" viewBox="-9 0 20 20" data-rating="2">
              <path d="M10.53 16.081l6.5 3.926-1.72-7.4 5.74-4.98-7.56-.65-2.96-6.981-2.96 6.981-7.56.65 5.74 4.98-1.72 7.4z" style="fill-rule:nonzero;"></path>
            </svg>
  <svg class="star rating star2-2" width="22" height="22" viewBox="10 0 20 20" data-rating="2.5">
              <path d="M10.53 16.081l6.5 3.926-1.72-7.4 5.74-4.98-7.56-.65-2.96-6.981-2.96 6.981-7.56.65 5.74 4.98-1.72 7.4z" style="fill-rule:nonzero;"></path>
            </svg>
  <svg class="star rating star3" width="22" height="22" viewBox="-9 0 20 20" data-rating="3">
              <path d="M10.53 16.081l6.5 3.926-1.72-7.4 5.74-4.98-7.56-.65-2.96-6.981-2.96 6.981-7.56.65 5.74 4.98-1.72 7.4z" style="fill-rule:nonzero;"></path>
            </svg>
  <svg class="star rating star3-2" width="22" height="22" viewBox="10 0 20 20" data-rating="3.5">
              <path d="M10.53 16.081l6.5 3.926-1.72-7.4 5.74-4.98-7.56-.65-2.96-6.981-2.96 6.981-7.56.65 5.74 4.98-1.72 7.4z" style="fill-rule:nonzero;"></path>
            </svg>
  <svg class="star rating star4" width="22" height="22" viewBox="-9 0 20 20" data-rating="4">
              <path d="M10.53 16.081l6.5 3.926-1.72-7.4 5.74-4.98-7.56-.65-2.96-6.981-2.96 6.981-7.56.65 5.74 4.98-1.72 7.4z" style="fill-rule:nonzero;"></path>
            </svg>
  <svg class="star rating star4-2" width="22" height="22" viewBox="10 0 20 20" data-rating="4.5">
              <path d="M10.53 16.081l6.5 3.926-1.72-7.4 5.74-4.98-7.56-.65-2.96-6.981-2.96 6.981-7.56.65 5.74 4.98-1.72 7.4z" style="fill-rule:nonzero;"></path>
            </svg>
  <svg class="star rating star5" width="22" height="22" viewBox="-9 0 20 20" data-rating="5">
              <path d="M10.53 16.081l6.5 3.926-1.72-7.4 5.74-4.98-7.56-.65-2.96-6.981-2.96 6.981-7.56.65 5.74 4.98-1.72 7.4z" style="fill-rule:nonzero;"></path>
            </svg>
  <svg class="star rating star5-2" width="22" height="22" viewBox="10 0 20 20" data-rating="5.5">
              <path d="M10.53 16.081l6.5 3.926-1.72-7.4 5.74-4.98-7.56-.65-2.96-6.981-2.96 6.981-7.56.65 5.74 4.98-1.72 7.4z" style="fill-rule:nonzero;"></path>
            </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: То что есть на данный момент, не совсем правильно. Как вариант, можно сделать чтобы у нас было пять настоящих звёзд (без дополнительных скрытых), а команду на закрашивание их, будем давать через JS, с помощью простой математики. Сам алгоритм: Пользователь наводит на звезду > Узнаем в какой области звезды, находиться мышка > И в зависимости от области, закрашиваем нам нужную. 
По поводу **Узнаем в какой области звезды** почитать можно вот [тут](http://shpargalkablog.ru/2013/05/get-mouse-coordinates-inside-div.html).
Возможно не лучший вариант, но вариант =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Ну как вариант:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ratingElem = $('.rating input[name="star"]');

  ratingElem.change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.rating {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 2em;
}

.rating input[name=star] {
  display: none;
  width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left: -2px;
}

.rating input[name=star]:focus~label svg {
  fill: #f2a200;
}

.rating input[name=star]:checked~label svg {
  fill: #f2a200;
}

.rating span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}

.rating span label {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.rating span label svg {
  fill: #CCC;
  color: transparent;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.rating span label:hover svg {
  fill: #f2a200;
}

.rating span label:hover~label svg {
  fill: #f2a200;
}

.rating span label:hover~label.half svg {
  fill: #f2a200;
}

.rating span label.half {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
}

.rating span label.half svg {
  fill: none;
}

.rating span label.half:hover svg {
  fill: #f2a200;
}

.rating span:hover~span label svg {
  fill: #f2a200;
}

.rating span.active~span label svg {
  fill: #f2a200;
}

fieldset {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <symbol id="star" viewBox="0 0 28 28" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax meet">
            <title>Star Rating</title>
            <path class="star"
                  d="M13.996,22.501 L22.649,27.997 L20.352,17.637 L27.996,10.667 L17.930,9.768 L13.996,-0.003 L10.063,9.768 L-0.003,10.667 L7.641,17.637 L5.345,27.997 L13.996,22.501 Z"/>
        </symbol>
</svg>


<div class="container">
  <div class="rating">
    <fieldset class="rating-fieldset">
      <span><input type="checkbox" id="star5" class="rating-checkbox" value="5" name="star" /><label class="full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars">
                                                        <svg role="img" aria-label="rating">
                                                            <use xlink:href="#star"></use>
                                                        </svg>
                                                    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="star4half" class="rating-checkbox" value="4.5" name="star" /><label class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars" name="star">    <svg role="img" aria-label="rating">                                                 <use xlink:href="#star"></use>                                           </svg>                                 
      </label></span>
      <span> <input type="checkbox" id="star4" class="rating-checkbox" value="4" name="star" /><label class="full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars">
                                                        <svg role="img" aria-label="rating">
                                                            <use xlink:href="#star"></use>
                                                        </svg>
                                                    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="star3half" class="rating-checkbox" value="3.5" name="star" /><label class="half" for="star3half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars">   <svg role="img" aria-label="rating">                                                 <use xlink:href="#star"></use>                                           </svg>                                
     </label></span>
      <span><input type="checkbox" id="star3" class="rating-checkbox" value="3" name="star" /><label class="full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars" name="star">
                                                        <svg role="img" aria-label="rating">
                                                            <use xlink:href="#star"></use>
                                                        </svg>
                                                    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="star2half" class="rating-checkbox" value="2.5" name="star" /><label class="half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars">   <svg role="img" aria-label="rating">                                                 <use xlink:href="#star"></use>                                           </svg>                                  
      </label></span>
      <span><input type="checkbox" id="star2" class="rating-checkbox" value="2" name="star" /><label class="full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars">
                                                        <svg role="img" aria-label="rating">
                                                            <use xlink:href="#star"></use>
                                                        </svg>
                                                    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="star1half" class="rating-checkbox" value="1.5" name="star" /><label class="half" for="star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars">  <svg role="img" aria-label="rating">                                                 <use xlink:href="#star"></use>                                           </svg>                                   
      </label></span>
      <span><input type="checkbox" id="star1" class="rating-checkbox" value="1" name="star" /><label class="full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star">
                                                        <svg role="img" aria-label="rating">
                                                            <use xlink:href="#star"></use>
                                                        </svg>
                                                    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="starhalf" class="rating-checkbox" value="0.5" name="star" /><label class="half" for="starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars">
      <svg role="img" aria-label="rating">                                                 <use xlink:href="#star"></use>                                           </svg>
      </label></span>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за твое решение! Наведение отрабатывает отлично как и хотелось. Буду разбираться со скриптом.. странное поведение в браузере с локального сервера.. заливается только та звезда (или половина) в которой произошел клик.

Comment: @Андрей, не за что, если Вас удовлетворил ответ, то поставьте слева от ответа галочку, это, в будущем, поможет людям, которые ищут ответ на похожий вопрос. Желаю успехов!